# AWS dynamoDB correct data modeling and master/detail relationship?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, datamodel

I have a pretty strong sql background and trying to design a database structure in dynamodb. I have a hierarchical structure some thing like below:

```
{
"Services" :[
    {
    "ServiceId": 123,
    "ServiceName": "Service 1",
    "Categories": [
     {
        "CategoryId":1,
        "Category Name": "Cat 1"
         "Products":[
            {
            "ProudctID: 1,
            "ProductName: Prod1
            },
            {
            "ProudctID: 2,
            "ProductName: Prod2
            }
        ]
     },
     {
        "CategoryId":2,
        "Category Name": "Cat 2"
         "Products":[
            {
            "ProudctID: 1,
            "ProductName: Prod1
            },
            {
            "ProudctID: 2,
            "ProductName: Prod2
            }
        ]
     }
 ]

},
{
    "ServiceId": 224,
    "ServiceName": "Service 2",
    "Categories": [
     {
        "CategoryId":1,
        "Category Name": "Cat 1"
         "Products":[
            {
            "ProudctID: 1,
            "ProductName: Prod1
            },
            {
            "ProudctID: 2,
            "ProductName: Prod2
            }
        ]
     },
     {
        "CategoryId":2,
        "Category Name": "Cat 2"
         "Products":[
            {
            "ProudctID: 1,
            "ProductName: Prod1
            },
            {
            "ProudctID: 2,
            "ProductName: Prod2
            }
        ]
     }
 ]

}

]
}
```

so its like we have multiple services each service has different categories and each catageory has different products. I am thinking about structuring some thing like following:

**Product Table:**

ProductId,
ProductName

**Category Table:**

CategoryId
CategoryName

**Service Table:**

serviceid,
servicename

**ProductCatalog Table:**

ProductId,
CategoryID,
ServiceID

Is this the correct modeling?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct modeling?

Yes, Could it be wrong for the use case your are trying to solve, possibly yes.
But without any content its hard to help you in validating your Content Modeling.

*Side note the Json you provide does not match your structure you describe below. Your Json talks about "Services", where the structure talks about "ProductCatalog".*

Comment: yes, it should have been "Product Catalog" at the top and every thing under it. but idea is some thing like a typical ecommerce application where u have services on top and each service has different categories and each category has different products so on and so forth. In normal sql like database we could have some thing like the following structure **Service Table**:

id, name etc

**Category**:

id, serviceid, name, etc

**product**:

id, categoryid, serviceid, name etc  and we might not need the fourth table to query the data. can we go with this structure instead?

Comment: Why are you not just doing it in SQL? - If knowledge is missing, and knowing a typical eCommerce system can quickly grow to something more complex, and as @acollao mentions below with search, indexes etc the power of SQL might out way No-SQL architecture.

Comment: for some reason currently dynamodb is the only option. I m just interested to find the better approach between these 2 options. i.e. option1 with 4 tables and option 2 with 3 tables?

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I saw a conference about modeling database for NoSql database. For a few cases is valid use a model like master/detail tables structure.

At the same time my recomendation Is thinking what kind of search you need over dynamo, because Is posible you need create secundary indexes. This impact in the cost of your plataform.